# Ormlite not profiled with ServiceStack MVC profiler

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have the MVC profiler in my service stack web services and I see requests being logged to Nlog.

However, when I try to profile my PostgreSQL database, no logs are generated.

I have in my global.asax.cs:

```
        var dbConnectionFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
            "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=mydatabase;User 
                                          Id=id;Password=password;")

                                      {
                                          ConnectionFilter = x => new 
                                      ProfiledDbConnection(x, Profiler.Current)
                                      };

        builder.RegisterInstance(dbConnectionFactory).
                         ExternallyOwned().As<IDbConnectionFactory>();

         var autofacContainer = builder.Build();
        //set Autofac as default Dependency Resolver for application
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new 
                                  AutofacDependencyResolver(autofacContainer));
```

and

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.IsLocal)
        {
            Profiler.Start();
        } 
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Profiler.Current != null)
        {
            Logger.Debug("profiling result id:{0}\nresult:{1}", Profiler.Current.Id,Profiler.Current.Render());
        }
        Profiler.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Are you really using ServiceStack https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack? Because  `DependencyResolver.SetResolver` is an ASP.NET MVC thing and the `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest` events on the ASP.NET `System.Web.HttpApplication`...

Comment: Yes, from what I remember service stack can expose web services hosted in MVC. I copied Application beginRequest and endRequest from https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Built-in-profiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MiniProfiler isn't related to logging, it's controls whether or not the profiled results are visible on the MiniProfiler viewer (that's on [ServiceStack's auto-generated HTML5 Report pages](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/HTML5ReportFormat)).

You haven't shown any logging code here, (I'm assuming you're using [ServiceStack.Logging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Logging) with the NLog adapter). The best place to configure it is before you initialize the AppHost so all the static constructors use the configured Logging providers, i.e:

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new NLogFactory();
(new AppHost()).Init();
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was using the ILog interface but found that it was defined in another assembly and hence ServiceStack.Logging was not being used. I'll have switched to ServiceStack.Logging.NLog now. From your answer, am I wrong to assume that that the sql profiling will be written to an Nlog file? I am currently running a Flex Client and need to profile postgres.

Comment: The logging isn't done in the Profiler (it's got nothing to do with it), the likely logging in OrmLite you're referring to [is here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteDialectProviderBase.cs#L32) and it happens for **Debug** builds of OrmLite.

Comment: To get the debug build would I have to pull the source to and build in debug or can I get debug build binaries?

Comment: Yeah you'd have to compile from src, the alternative is to provide your own `ProfiledDbConnection` and `ProfiledDbCommand` that intercepts all queries and logs them.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I watched "quickly" the PluralSight course and saw SQL profiling and thought I could redirect it to a log file :)

Comment: I found the following which gives me timings:    if (Profiler.Current != null)
            {
                foreach (var sqlTiming in Profiler.Current.GetSqlTimings())
                {
                    Logger.Debug("{0} {1}", sqlTiming.DurationMilliseconds, sqlTiming.CommandString);
                }. This is what I need. Can I run with this or should I create a ProfiledDbConnection?

Comment: If it does what you need sure. Also another option is to submit a pull-request with a opt-in flag in the MiniProfiler that just enables logging :)